# while updating image it is not saved in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using Formidable and the fa-extra module of Node.js for storing files in MongoDB. It is working when I insert. but I'm not getting how to update using Formidable.

```
form.on('file',function(field, file){
  var temp = file.path;
  var fileName = file.name;
  var fileName = file.name;
  var location     = 'images/';
  var cpLocation   = 'empDetails/images/';
  empData.imgSize = file.size;*here empData is my instance of model*
  empData.imgType = file.type;
  empData.picFile = location+fileName;  **picFile is my mongodb row name in collection**
  fs.copy(temp,cpLocation+fileName ,function(err){
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

});

form.on('end',function(fields, files){
  empData.save(function(err,resobj){
    if(err)
    {    
      throw err;
    }
  });
});
```

`empData` is object for my model for storing these files. Up to here there is no problem. But I don't know how to change the image and update in MongoDB. My update query is below.

```
exports.updateEmpData=function(req,res){
  var temp = req.param('empID');
  console.log(temp,'hjsdbjhdvbdhfvbdhbvj');

  EmpDetail.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:temp},{$set:{"picFile":req.body.picFile},
    function(err,obj){
      if(err){
        return err;
      }
      else{
        res.json(obj);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: yes its not saving in db

Answer (score 0):

Your findByIdAndUpdate method looks wrong. The correct syntax is:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, {new: true}, function(err, model)
```

So in your case the syntax will be:

```
EmpDetail.findByIdAndUpdate(temp,{$set:{"picFile":req.body.picFile},
function(err,obj){
  if(err){
    return err;
  }
  else{
    res.json(obj);

  }
});
```

ref: [Link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: here EmpDetail means
var empData = new EmpDetail()

Comment: did you try changing the syntax?

Comment: yes my fields are updating but image is not updating